# Even distribution of roughly 16 dots in a rectangle

Tags: geometry, optimization

I'm about to grow lettuces on a hydroponic system and I was wondering what would be the ideal pattern to provide each lettuce with the max space.
Would it be better to plant them according to a grid like on the picture below or to a "brick" pattern such as "one row of 5, then one row of 4 and so on" or any other even better pattern?
The number of pots is currently 16, but I don't mind slightly altering this if this is required by an ideal pattern.
Obviously, this must also include the space from the last pots/rows to the edges of the total rectangle.
The size of the total area is 120cm x 80cm (47.24 in x 31.5 in)

Thanks a lot in advance for your help
[image: Pots distribution]

Comment: How much space does each plant need?

Comment: The typical lettuce has a diameter of 25cm

Comment: With a 4x4 grid your minimum distance between pots is only 20 cm. With this arrangement you can get a little over 23 cm: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RMvYU.png If you reduce to 15 pots, a simple 5x3 grid will give you a separation of 24 cm.

Comment: Here's a 14-pot solution with a separation over 25 cm: http://i.stack.imgur.com/k7cwV.png

Comment: OK thanks. I've done it according to a hexagonal pattern, which is definitely the optimal solution and I've only left 10cm on the sides as the leaves can overpass the edges without problems.

Comment: @Rahul: I think your pictures would make for a nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some code to compute packings of disks into a $120\times80$ rectangle. Here are the results for up to 20 disks, along with the disk diameter for each. No guarantees of global optimality.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rahul. You are the genius I've been waiting for!

Comment: Here is the final picture with 18 pots and about 24cm between them. I cheated a little bit, because I only left 10cm on the sides. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By-S838OebDHWWNNN0FTVFBuUnc/view?usp=sharing